# Remove JavaScript code from page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a chunk of JavaScript code:

```
 <script src='blah.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

How can this be removed or disabled with JavaScript?

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss2.shtml

Comment: Not really, no. Take effort to get it out of the source that is sent to the client (wether that may be by editing the file, setting server configs, or creating a proxy is up to you)

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you need this to be removed or disabled (and why did you think you would use JS)?

Comment: It's for a PayPal digital goods page which much include a PayPal JS file. However I need to toggle this part of code and disable certain effects of the script if the user requests a free download instead of paying.

Comment: @scottpaterson: While a script can't be removed, it certainly can be *added*. Generate the page without the script then add when needed, rather than having it in the page and trying to undo it when you don't want it.

Answer (score 1):

If the script tag is received in a string via AJAX:

```
str = str.replace("<script src='blah.js' type='text/javascript'></script>", "");
```

However, if the script tag is in the current document, there is no way to disable it, because:

- If it is in the part of the document which has already been parsed (i.e. above the current script), it has already been executed. While you can remove the script *element*, just like any element, there is no way to rewind time and automatically undo the effects the script has.
- If it is in the part of the document which has not yet been parsed (i.e. below the current script), you cannot affect it, as it does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the script like any other element, you can do this:

```
document.querySelector("script").remove();
```

If you have a lot of script tags you can just grab the one you want like accessing a array element like so:

```
document.querySelectorAll("script")[1].remove();
```

The code above removes the second script tag in a page.